# How to interrogate snap svg event object to get viewbox coordinate?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I have a simple svg file containing 2 rectangles and a text :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->
<svg id="mySvg" onload="init()" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" height="100%" width="100%" version="1.1" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" viewBox="0 0 1371.4286 773.5047">

<script xlink:href="snap.svg-min.js" type="text/ecmascript"/>
<rect id="blackRect" style="color-rendering:auto;color:#000000;isolation:auto;mix-blend-mode:normal;shape-rendering:auto;solid-color:#000000;image-rendering:auto" ry=".16344" height="773.5" width="1371.4" y="161.71" x="-371.43" fill="#ffb380"/>
<rect id="hoverTarget"   style="color-rendering:auto;color:#000000;isolation:auto;mix-blend-mode:normal;shape-rendering:auto;solid-color:#000000;image-rendering:auto" ry=".098402" height="177.14" width="286.62" y="369.51" x="180" fill="#008080"/>

<text id="viewboxText" style="word-spacing:0px;letter-spacing:0px" font-weight="bold" xml:space="preserve" font-size="27.5px" line-height="125%" y="810.93359" x="-3.165039e-005" font-family="sans-serif" fill="#000000"><tspan id="tspan3348" x="-3.165039e-005" y="810.93359">Viewbox :</tspan></text>
</svg>
```

and before the closing `</svg>` tag i added this script:

```
<script><![CDATA[
var mySvg, hoverTarget,  viewboxText;
function init(){
  mySvg=Snap("#mySvg");
  hoverTarget=mySvg.select("#hoverTarget"); 
  viewboxText=mySvg.select("#viewboxText");
  hoverTarget.mousemove(hoverCursor);
}

function hoverCursor(evt){
  var cursorX, cursorY;
  if(evt.type==="mousemove"){
    cursorX=...;
     /*this is my question : how to interrogate the evt object to get X position of the cursor 
    according to mySvg viewbox?*/
    cursorY=...;
    //and, of course, how to get Y position from the evt object..

    //and after that, display it on the text...
    viewboxText.attr({text : "X : " + cursorX + ", Y : " + cursorY});
  }
}
]]></script>
```

My question is : is there any way to interrogate snap event object of the event handler function to obtain viewbox coordinate of the svg parent element?

If there is, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I think you may be after...

First we get the inverse matrix from the element to the screen

```
var m = Snap.matrix( evt.target.getScreenCTM().inverse() )

// you may want to use this instead, but should be same for this case
// var m = Snap.matrix( mySvg.node.getScreenCTM().inverse() )

var newX = m.x( cursorX, cursorY )
var newY = m.y( cursorX, cursorY )
```

m.x(), m.y() convert the x,y coordinates with the new matrix.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ian_b/qf5eh5bz/6/)